# WinUnit testing a native dll on a machine without visual studio

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, dll

I am wondering how I can test a dll with WinUnit on a machine without Visual Studio IDE? 
I did some search, but it looks like WinUnit test need IDE installed on the testing machine.
So, should I use command line such as `WinUnit.exe -someargument MyTest.dll`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using winunit tesing A.dll which calls B.dll; I want to test all functions with So here is what the command line looks like

```
WinUnit -p FunctionsInAdllYouWantToTest --YourEnvioronmentVariable "YourPathOfBdll\B.dll" "YourPathOfAdll\A.dll"
```

something like above.